# Itemize inside algorithm block Lonely \item error

Tags: errors, itemize, algorithms

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%

\begin{document}
    
\begin{algorithm}
\State \textbf{Inputs:} 

\begin{itemize}
    \item Input 1
    \item Input 2
\end{itemize}

\For{each pixel at row, column (x,y)}
    \State Formula 1
    \State Formula 2
    \State Formula 3
    \State Formula 4
\EndFor
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the text to look exactly like the image here. However, the above latex file gives error "Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment". It still compiles and gives the correct output, but the error keeps popping up.

The other answer I found on StackExchange either have no text bullet, or all text bullet.

How can I put itemize inside `algorithm` like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`algorithm`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) just provide the `algorithm` float. You need an `algorithmic` environment to set the algorithm:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \State \textbf{Inputs:} 

    \begin{itemize}
      \item Input 1
      \item Input 2
    \end{itemize}

    \For{each pixel at row, column $(x,y)$}
      \State Formula 1
      \State Formula 2
      \State Formula 3
      \State Formula 4
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It still gives "Missing \endcsname inserted" at line "Inputs" and "For{...}"

Comment: Nevermind. The problem was using both  "algorithmic" and "algpseudocode" packages. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @DukeLe: True. `algpseudocode` is what you actually need from [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) since it includes all the necessary components for use within the `algorithmic` environment.